# Enterprise Library reference causing Azure DevFabric crash

Tags: azure, enterprise-library

This one's driving me a bit bonkers today!

I have an Azure app that I'm beefing up. Today's exercise is to implement exception handling using Enterprise Library 5.0's Exception Handling Application Block.

However, I've discovered that when I add a reference to Microsoft.Practives.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling, my web role (an MVC 2 UI) crashes in wawebhost.exe.

I can add references to the assemblies on which ExceptionHandling depends, namely

- Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common
- Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation
- Microsoft.Practices.Unity (which I've
  already been using successfully)
- Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Interception

I can add a reference to the Logging Application Block, just fine.

But as soon as I add a reference to the pesky Exception Handling Application Block and hit F5, BANG!

> ```
> Microsoft Windows Azure Web Host has stopped working
> Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
> Application Name: WaWebHost.exe
> Fault Module Name: KERNELBASE.dll
> ```

Help??

[Update] I've been through and tried all of the other application blocks, too. Adding a reference to the Cryptography application block yields the same result but all the others seem fine...

Comment: That's correct. You may also want to check out this [guide](http://www.codeplex.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=wag&DownloadId=111359) on using Enterprise Library in Azure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oooh, now I'm cross!

It turned out that the fully qualified path to Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.dll was longer than 260 characters but the path to Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.dll wasn't. Similarly with the Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Security.Cryptography.dll.

Problem 'resolved' by changing the meaningful project name to "UI"!